# SQLAlchemy index error on Pulling data from Google Analytics

Tags: python, postgresql, google-analytics, sqlalchemy, google-analytics-api

I'm using a python script to fetch data from Google Analytics and i'm getting the below error.
What this error is and how to resolve it?

```
05:04:31 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.errors.ProgramLimitExceeded) index row size 2792 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index "ga_events_pkey"
05:04:31 DETAIL:  Index row references tuple (42550,53) in relation "ga_events".
05:04:31 HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
05:04:31 Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

**Below is the current primary key**

What change i need to do on this primary key, Seen lot of posts to create an index based on md5. But i'm confused whether i need to remove the below index and recreate index? Or create a new one and md5 on all columns?

```
ALTER TABLE dl_ga.ga_events
    ADD CONSTRAINT ga_events_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ga:date", "ga:eventCategory", "ga:eventAction", "ga:eventLabel", "ga:source", "ga:medium", "ga:campaign", view_id);
```

Tried to modify the index like below,
But getting error. How can this be created to avoid this error?

```
ALTER TABLE dl_ga.ga_events ADD CONSTRAINT ga_events_pkey PRIMARY KEY( 
md5("ga:date"), md5("ga:eventCategory"), md5("ga:eventAction")
, md5("ga:eventLabel"), md5("ga:source"), md5("ga:medium")
, md5("ga:campaign"), md5(view_id)
);
```

Code where exception is throwing:

```
if data:
   push_data_to_pg(pg_client, ga_load_config.dl_schema,
   f"{ga_load_config.table_prefix}_{ga_load_config.report_name}", data,primary_key_columns=dimensions)
```

Sample insert query:

```
    [SQL: INSERT INTO dl_ga.ga_events ("ga:date", "ga:eventCategory", "ga:eventAction", "ga:eventLabel", "ga:source", "ga:medium", "ga:campaign", "ga:uniqueEvents", "ga:totalEvents", view_id) VALUES (%(ga:date_m0)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m0)s, %(ga:eventAction_m0)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m0)s, %(ga:source_m0)s, %(ga:medium_m0)s, %(ga:campaign_m0)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m0)s
, %(ga:totalEvents_m0)s, %(view_id_m0)s), (%(ga:date_m1)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m1)s, %(ga:eventAction_m1)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m1)s, %(ga:source_m1)s, %(ga:medium_m1)s, %(ga:campaign_m1)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m1)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m1)s, %(view_id_m1)s), (%(ga:date_m2)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m2)s, %(ga:eventAction_m2)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m2)s, %(ga:source_m2)s, %(ga:medium_m2)s, %(ga:campaign_m2)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m2)s
, %(ga:totalEvents_m2)s, %(view_id_m2)s), (%(ga:date_m3)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m3)s, %(ga:eventAction_m3)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m3)s, %(ga:source_m3)s, %(ga:medium_m3)s, %(ga:campaign_m3)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m3)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m3)s, %(view_id_m3)s), (%(ga:date_m4)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m4)s, %(ga:eventAction_m4)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m4)s, %(ga:source_m4)s, %(ga:medium_m4)s, %(ga:campaign_m4)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m4)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m4)s, %(view_id_m4)s), (%(ga:date_m5)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m5)s, %(ga:eventAction_m5)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m5)s, %(ga:source_m5)s, %(ga:medium_m5)s, %(ga:campaign_m5)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m5)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m5)s, %(view_id_m5)s)
, (%(ga:date_m6)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m6)s, %(ga:eventAction_m6)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m6)s, %(ga:source_m6)s, %(ga:medium_m6)s, %(ga:campaign_m6)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m6)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m6)s, %(view_id_m6)s), (%(ga:date_m7)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m7)s, %(ga:eventAction_m7)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m7)s, %(ga:source_m7)s, %(ga:medium_m7)s, %(ga:campaign_m7)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m7)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m7)s, %(view_id_m7)s), (%(ga:date_m8)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m8)s, %(ga:eventAction_m8)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m8)s, %(ga:source_m8)s, %(ga:medium_m8)s
, %(ga:campaign_m8)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m8)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m8)s, %(view_id_m8)s), (%(ga:date_m9)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m9)s, %(ga:eventAction_m9)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m9)s, %(ga:source_m9)s, %(ga:medium_m9)s, %(ga:campaign_m9)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m9)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m9)s, %(view_id_m9)s), (%(ga:date_m10)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m10)s, %(ga:eventAction_m10)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m10)s, %(ga:source_m10)s, %(ga:medium_m10)s, %(ga:campaign_m10)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m10)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m10)s, %(view_id_m10)s), (%(ga:date_m11)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m11)s, %(ga:eventAction_m11)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m11)s, %(ga:source_m11)s, %(ga:medium_m11)s, %(ga:campaign_m11)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m11)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m11)s, %(view_id_m11)s), (%(ga:date_m12)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m12)s, %(ga:eventAction_m12)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m12)s, %(ga:source_m12)s, %(ga:medium_m12)s, %(ga:campaign_m12)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m12)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m12)s, %(view_id_m12)s), (%(ga:date_m13)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m13)s, %(ga:eventAction_m13)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m13)s, %(ga:source_m13)s, %(ga:medium_m13)s
, %(ga:campaign_m13)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m13)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m13)s, %(view_id_m13)s), (%(ga:date_m14)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m14)s, %(ga:eventAction_m14)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m14)s, %(ga:source_m14)s, %(ga:medium_m14)s, %(ga:campaign_m14)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m14)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m14)s, %(view_id_m14)s), (%(ga:date_m15)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m15)s, %(ga:eventAction_m15)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m15)s, %(ga:source_m15)s, %(ga:medium_m15)s, %(ga:campaign_m15)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m15)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m15)s, %(view_id_m15)s), (%(ga:date_m16)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m16)s, %(ga:eventAction_m16)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m16)s, %(ga:source_m16)s, %(ga:medium_m16)s, %(ga:campaign_m16)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m16)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m16)s, %(view_id_m16)s), (%(ga:date_m17)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m17)s, %(ga:eventAction_m17)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m17)s, %(ga:source_m17)s, %(ga:medium_m17)s, %(ga:campaign_m17)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m17)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m17)s, %(view_id_m17)s), (%(ga:date_m18)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m18)s, %(ga:eventAction_m18)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m18)s, %(ga:source_m18)s, %(ga:medium_m18)s, %(ga:campaign_m18)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m18)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m18)s, %(view_id_m18)s), (%(ga:date_m19)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m19)s, %(ga:eventAction_m19)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m19)s, %(ga:source_m19)s, %(ga:medium_m19)s, %(ga:campaign_m19)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m19)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m19)s, %(view_id_m19)s), (%(ga:date_m20)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m20)s, %(ga:eventAction_m20)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m20)s, %(ga:source_m20)s, %(ga:medium_m20)s, %(ga:campaign_m20)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m20)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m20)s, %(view_id_m20)s), (%(ga:date_m21)s, %(ga:eventCategory_m21)s, %(ga:eventAction_m21)s, %(ga:eventLabel_m21)s, %(ga:source_m21)s, %(ga:medium_m21)s, %(ga:campaign_m21)s, %(ga:uniqueEvents_m21)s, %(ga:totalEvents_m21)s, %(view_id_m21)s), (%(ga:date_m22)s, %
```

Comment: This may help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162820/values-larger-than-1-3-of-a-buffer-page-cannot-be-indexed

Comment: @snakecharmerb I saw a lot of posts to create an index based on md5, But above is my table structure.Could you please let me know what change i need to make?